# How to remove an "ignored" or "favorite" tag?

Tags: support

On my Preferences page, under *Favorite Tags* and *Ignored Tags*, there is only an *Add* button -- so, if a tag is Added to either of these, how can it later be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next to each tag in the list, there's a cross symbol. Click.

Comment: Ouch. Thank you.